# Trailing Question Mark Issue in Regular Expression

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to redirect URLs containing the argument "args" with the WordPress Redirection plugin.

For example, redirect
    **website.com/page.htm?args=12345** 
to
    **website.com/page.htm**

The regular expression I tried is

```
/(.*)?args=(.*)  --> /$1
```

But this redirects to
    **website.com/page.htm?**
with a trailing question mark

When I tried the expression:

```
/(.*)?args=(.*)  --> /$1?
```

It redirects to **website.com/page.htm??**

What am I doing wrong here?

BTW, server redirection is not an option here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are selecting everything before `args=` in first case and in the second case you are not matching the `?` literally it should be `(.*)\?args=(.*)` escaped `?` for it to work

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/jV1sF3

Comment: rubular is slow and it won't describe whats happening

Comment: Thank you @aelor I didn't escape the question mark. Appreciate your quick reply. Have a good day!